# How to replace styles of an Excel sheet cell with no style and then add value to cell?

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I have inherited an Excel sheet (from a previous employee) that uses background color to convey information, rather than placing values in the cells.

Update: I should have mentioned that, although the document is an Excel sheet, our office is using LibreOffice for our suite. I think that LibreOffice uses StarBasic rather than VBscript.

Currently, this Excel sheet is looked at by human eyes only, but soon this sheet will be fed into a larger system. It will make more sense for this particular column in the sheet to have actual data rather than just styles.

How can I search/replace all cells in a column of data based on styling of the cell, AND add a value in the place of the background color.

1. if the cell has a background color (in this case: black), replace that with no background color.
2. then, add some value into the cell (for this sheet, a simple TRUE or FALSE should probably be good enough)

Very rough pseudo-code for what I hope to be able to do:

```
for each ( cell in column-X of sheet(1) ) {
    if cell.background.color == BLACK {
        cell.background.color = NO_BACKGROUND_COLOR
        cell.value = "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: You mentioned Styles, but it seems that these are just cell color formatted, please confirm.

Comment: @EEM - Yes, you are correct. It is just background color of the cell.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the cell changes required affect only the `color` and `contents` of the `cells`.

The changes can be done all in one run, provided a little bit of planning is done before, with a table like this information:

```
| Actual | Color | Change |
```

To explain graphically how to obtain the `colors` to be replace, lets assume the picture below represents the table that we need to apply the changes to:

[image]

To determine the `color` of the cell we’ll use the Immediate Window.
In the VBA editor, press Ctrl+G to open the Immediate Window.
Select in Excel one cell with a `color` to replace.
Type `?activecell.interior.color` in the Immediate Window to obtain the `color` of the cell.

[image]

Repeat for each `color`.
This the Table completed.

[image]

We’ll use the [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) to apply the table with the action for each `color`

```
Sub Cell_Color_Replace()
Dim rTrg As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        
        Rem To set all used cells in the worksheet as the target range
        Set rTrg = .UsedRange

        Rem A method to set the range
        Set rTrg = .UsedRange.Columns(11)
        
        Rem Another method to set the range
        Set rTrg = .Range("K7:K30")
    
    End With
    
    Call Cell_Color_Replace_APPLY(rTrg)

    End Sub
```

…

I broke the method in two procedures so the key procedure below can be called from any other procedure.

```
Sub Cell_Color_Replace_APPLY(rTrg As Range)
Dim rCll As Range
Dim vValue As Variant    'variant to allow different datatypes
    
    For Each rCll In rTrg.Cells
        With rCll
            
            Select Case .Interior.Color
            Case 13561798:       vValue = True
            Case 13551615:      vValue = "BAD"
            Case 10284031:      vValue = 1234
            Case Else:          vValue = "¡NOACTION"
            End Select
        
            If vValue <> "¡NOACTION" Then
                .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                .Value = vValue
            End If
                            
    End With: Next
    
    End Sub
```

And this is the range adjusted, note that I used styles that include `font.color` format, so the performance of the method is visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Pseudo-code' is definitely along the right lines.
I had to do something similar myself once - Try the below, it's quite crude but should do the trick;

```
Sub ChangeBackground()

Dim MacroRange as Range
Set MacroRange = Activesheet.Range("A:A") 'replace this with whatever range you want the macro to affect,
                      ' I originally just used ActiveSheet.Usedrange to do the whole sheet

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim Colour As Long
Colour = Selection.Interior.Color
Debug.Print Colour

For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.MacroRange
    If rngCell.Interior.Color = Colour Then
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'no fill
        rngCell.value = "Value" 'insert desired value here
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

NB This uses `Activesheet` and `Selection` a lot !! (Bad form I know, but I had to do exactly the same once and it was just the quickest way of doing it at the time). Before starting this macro, you'll need to have the desired workbook and sheet activated, and a cell with the colour to be replaced selected.
In my case I had multiple colours to replace but just did them one at a time (they needed different values), hence the `Selection` element to pick the colour.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have a feeling this is very close. However, while the document is an Excel sheet, our office is using LibreOffice. I think LibreOffice uses StarBasic, not VBscript. I get the error, "BASIC syntax error. Unknown data type Range." So, I am not sure what StarBasic uses in place of "Range"